# Misalignment of two synced ScrollPanes

Tags: java, javafx, vertical-alignment, vertical-scrolling, scrollpane

I try to align the vertical scroll position of two [javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ScrollPane.html)s via

```
sp1.vvalueProperty().bindBidirectional(sp2.vvalueProperty());
```

The problem is that one of these ScrollPanes may have a horizontal scroll bar. So the more I scroll down the ScrollPanes, the more they get misaligned (see screenshot). How can I handle this?

[image: javafx scollpane misaligned]

Comment: You could make both/all `ScrollPane`s always have a horizontal scroll bar or never have a horizontal scroll bar. See [`ScrollPane.hbarPolicy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/scene/control/ScrollPane.html#hbarPolicyProperty).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's impossible to do this with 2 `ScrollPane`s and contents of equal height unless you display the scrollbar in both `ScrollPane`s:

Consider the case where the content fits the `viewport` of the left `ScrollPane` exactly. The `viewPort` of the right `ScrollPane` can be scrolled by the `ScrollBar` height. Modifying the left `ScrollPane` is not possible.

Since the expected result seems to be some kind of scale, you could simply use a `Pane` with a child you apply `transformY` to and a clip. The formula to calculate the pixel to be placed at the top, use

```
top = vvalue * (contentHeight - viewportHeight)
```

#### Example

```
private static Label createLabel(int num, boolean mark) {
    Label label = new Label(Integer.toString(num));
    label.setPrefSize(50, 50);
    label.setMaxSize(Double.MAX_VALUE, Region.USE_PREF_SIZE);
    label.setStyle(mark ? "-fx-background-color: #FFFFFF" : "-fx-background-color: #BBBBBB;");
    return label;
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    VBox scale = new VBox();
    scale.setMinHeight(Region.USE_PREF_SIZE);
    GridPane content = new GridPane();

    for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
        boolean b = ((i % 2) == 0);
        scale.getChildren().add(createLabel(i, !b));

        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            content.add(createLabel(i * 10 + j, b), j, i);
        }
    }

    AnchorPane scaleContainer = new AnchorPane(scale);
    scaleContainer.setMinWidth(30);
    scaleContainer.setMinHeight(0);
    AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(scale, 0d);
    AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(scale, 0d);

    Rectangle clip = new Rectangle();
    scaleContainer.setClip(clip);
    clip.widthProperty().bind(scaleContainer.widthProperty());
    clip.heightProperty().bind(scaleContainer.heightProperty());

    ScrollPane scroll = new ScrollPane(content);

    scale.translateYProperty().bind(Bindings.createDoubleBinding(() -> {
        double contentHeight = content.getHeight();
        double viewportHeight = scroll.getViewportBounds().getHeight();
        if (contentHeight <= viewportHeight) {
            return 0d;
        } else {
            return -scroll.getVvalue() * (contentHeight - viewportHeight);
        }
    }, scroll.viewportBoundsProperty(), scroll.vvalueProperty(), content.heightProperty()));

    HBox root = new HBox(scaleContainer, scroll);
    root.setPadding(new Insets(10));

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```